# How do I install Migration Manager with Plesk already installed?

Tags: rhel5

I'm running Plesk 9.2 on RHEL 5.

I just installed it only to realize that 9.2 supports, but doesn't **include** Migration Manager by default.

What's the easiest way to install Migration Manager without having to redo the entire install?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plesk's Migration Manager can be easily installed with /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/autoinstaller.  Just start it up, go to the Components menu, select PMM (Plesk Migration Manager), and click through the installer.

Answer (score 2):

In other Plesk versions you could add modules post-install from the software updater.